# Why can't I call /usr/bin/xfce4-find-cursor on Xubuntu 20.04?

Tags: permissions, xubuntu, mouse, xfce, cursor

In order to switch between workplaces and simultaneously highlight the current mouse cursor position, I have associated shortcuts to certain keys. They activate one the commands

```
sh -c "wmctrl -s 0; xfce4-find-cursor"
sh -c "wmctrl -s 1; xfce4-find-cursor"
sh -c "wmctrl -s 2; xfce4-find-cursor"
sh -c "wmctrl -s 3; xfce4-find-cursor"
```

depending on which key I press. These associations worked well on a Xubuntu 22.04 system, but the cursor highlighting part does not work on my Xubuntu 20.04. Switching workplaces works under Xubuntu 20.04.

Looking into it, I found that `ls -l /usr/bin/xfce4-find-cursor` returns

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18760 2020-04-12 18:15 /usr/bin/xfce4-find-cursor
```

`sudo /usr/bin/xfce4-find-cursor` works as expected: it highlights the current mouse cursor position on the screen. Apparently `xfce4-find-cursor` does nothing or is not even invoked, although the `x`-bit is present for `ugo`!

I tried to change owner rights such that my account becomes owner. But then I got this error message:

```
(process:3700): xfce4-accessibility-settings-ERROR **: 23:25:20.509: Failed to connect to xfconf daemon: Could not connect: Permission denied.
Trace/Breakpoint ausgelöst (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

Of course I reverted the owner back to `root:root` after I saw this error message.

**What does it mean?**

**How can I invoke** `xfce4-find-cursor` **as a normal user by a script under Xubuntu 20.04, such that it actually highlights the mouse cursor position?**